# Make File Linking Issue

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries

I am developing a module for kamailio, an open source PBX. I am trying to compile my c code into a shared object file. The code is dependent on other shared object in Kamailio so I need to link them, otherwise kamailio will not load the module without error.

Here is my Makefile:

```
include ../../Makefile.defs

auto_gen=
NAME=libproto.so
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -g -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/include/linux -I/usr/local/lib64/kamailio/
LDFLAGS=-shared
LIBS= -L'$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)' -ljvm -L/usr/local/src/kamailio-4.3/kamailio/modules/kam_module_elogj -L/usr/local/lib64/kamailio/
DEFS+=-DKAMAILIO_MOD_INTERFACE
include ../../Makefile.modules


SOURCE=jni_wrapper.c ProtoType.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCE:.c=.o)

all: $(SOURCE) $(NAME)

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(LIBS) $<

clean:
        rm -f $(EXEC); rm -f *~; rm -f .*.swp; rm -f .*.swo; rm -f *.o

java:
        javac ProtoType.java
        jar cf ProtoType.jar ProtoType.class
        javap -s -p ProtoType > sigs.txt
        cat sigs.txt
```

The directory the dependent files are in `/usr/local/lib64/kamailio/`
As you can see I include the libraries in make:

```
 CFLAGS= -g -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/include/linux -I/usr/local/lib64/kamailio/
```

Unfortunately this is still not getting linked with my shared object file. So when kamailio loads the module it complains about undefined symbols.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my Makefile?

Comment: You need `-l` arguments for the libraries you need to link to. You don't appear to have many of those. Do you need more? That said I wouldn't expect a module for a piece of software to need to link against libraries from the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to link against internal libraries of Kamailio, you should do it using the makefile variables SERLIBPATH and SER_LIBS. For example, look at the makefile of alias_db module, it needs to connect to database, therefore links against srdb1 library (abstract db api) -- the relevant snippet:

```
SERLIBPATH=../../lib
SER_LIBS+=$(SERLIBPATH)/srdb1/srdb1
```

You must no link a module to kamailio internal libraries after installing kamailio.